# Facebook destroy session on logout

Tags: php, facebook

I am doing a site for a client and they are using facebook login.. When I login and log out of facebook it works fine. But when I login shortly after I log out, it automatically logs in as the previous person who was logged in.  My question is how to destroy (I assume session or cookies) that is storing the info or will I need to expire the access token?  Either way was wandering if anyone had a solution that has worked for them recently as a quick fix is turning into a long problem because of this.

```
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION['FBID'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  NULL;
$_SESSION['valid']  = NULL;
 header("Location: " ."http://www.muchogusto.net");
```

Comment: without code, you are not likely to get an answer here

Comment: session_start();
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION['FBID'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  NULL;
    $_SESSION['valid']  = NULL;
     header("Location: " ."http://www.my-site.net");

Comment: I would suggest you add that to your question so it's properly formatted

Comment: didn't notice the edit button at first

Comment: BTW, why are you using two strings for the `Location` value?

Comment: BTW #2, for static strings, you should use single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"` so the interpreter doesn't have to parse them - faster and less resource intensive.

Comment: the two strings just hasn't been changed back from testing other ways.. had a variable in it for awhile

Comment: Facebook PHP SDK has a method to create a logout URL. (If you’re not using the SDK, check the source to see what this URL needs to look like. Needs two parameters, a valid user access token and a redirect URI.) That one, in combination with deletion of the locally set cookies afterwards, usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) man page

> In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) may be used for that.

---

**EDIT**

This is what I use:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
setcookie('PHPSESSID','',time()-864000,'/');    // persistent cookie
setcookie('PHPSESSID','',0,'/');    // session cookie
```

Add your code after that:

```
session_unset();
$_SESSION['FBID'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  NULL;
$_SESSION['valid']  = NULL;
header('Location: http://www.muchogusto.net');
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - how?  BTW, `setcookie` cannot be used after *anything* has been written to the browser.

Comment: doesn't work because as soon as i click on the log in button after logging out... It automatically still logs back into the previous facebook users login.

Comment: This is why I never originally used the code in the original post until someone mentioned to do it... The name of the SESSIONS are probably not correct, that's just the code I was originally told would work but doesn't.... So was more looking for someone who has recently made a logout page with a facebook login

Comment: What did you use for your `setcookie` parameters?  Did you destroy both the permanent and the session cookies as I illustrated?  (You should use those two lines verbatim.)

Comment: Also, if there's another browser window/tab open with a Facebook login active, you may not be actually able to log out without restarting the browser.

Comment: I don't work for facebook.... I don't know the parameters they use, from what I have figured out, it may have to do with oAuth 2.0 storing the info since that is who Facebook uses.

Comment: If the FB login is being stored in the PHP session, then destroying the `PHPSESSID` cookies will forcibly void the current session, and a new one will be created when the next page loads, which will have no FB login details in it.  If destroying the PHP session doesn't fix the problem, then it's not something in the PHP code, and you'll have to find an API on Facebook for doing a logout.